# How do I create a Cognito UserPool Authorizer with CDK when the UserPool is in another Account

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

If the the UserPool is in different account from the account that contains the API Gateway, how do you create an Authorizer?

Using `CognitoUserPoolsAuthorizer` we only seem to be able to pass in an `IUserPool` but I'm unable to import an existing UserPool if it's in a different account.

Comment: Does this describe your use case? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-cross-account-cognito-authorizer.html

Comment: @TestWell Yes.. i've done that from the console, but how can that be done via CDK, it doesn't seem to be available? If I could import the existing UserPool it would be fine, but that doesn't seem work. Just get an error saying the UserPool doesn't exist.

Comment: `IUserPool` appears to accept a user pool ARN: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cognito.IUserPool.html. I think you'd just grab that from the other account and pass it in as `userPoolArn`.

Comment: @TestWell not sure I understand, how do I do that?

Comment: Not sure which language you are using but something like this: const userPool = UserPool.fromUserPoolArn(this, "OtherAccountPool", "arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-west-2:1234567890:userpool/userPoolId"), if this is triggering it to load the pool and that fails because it's in another account, I don't know enough CDK to make a suggestion.

Comment: @TestWell That does seem to work.. 
`const userPool = UserPool.fromUserPoolArn(this, 'UserPool', props.userPoolArn);`
.. not sure how I didnt see that.